# export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: flask, export

I have used the 'export' command many a times in the past without a problem on my Windows 10 laptop. For example I would type 'export FLASK_APP=microblog.py' without a problem. Today (18 January 2021) i am suddenly getting the error: 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What could have changed on my machine?

Comment: Have you tried set instead of export? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/

Answer (score 11):

I apologize, I should have been using 'set' instead of 'export'.